# trouble creating nested dom nodes in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, nested, nodes, appendchild

I've a function that takes an object as a parameter, and uses the structure of the object to create nested DOM nodes, but I receive the following error:

```
http://new.app/:75NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

What I would like my function to do, is, when supplied with a suitable object as a parameter, example:

```
var nodes = {
    tweet: {
        children: {
            screen_name: {
                tag: "h2"
            },
            text: {
                tag: "p"
            }
        },
        tag: "article"
    }
};
```

It would create the following DOM nodes:

```
<article>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
</article>
```

Here is my attempt so far:

```
function create(obj) {
    for(i in obj){  
        var tmp = document.createElement(obj[i].tag);  
        if(obj[i].children) {  
            tmp.appendChild(create(obj[i].children)); /* error */
        }; 
        document.getElementById("tweets").appendChild(tmp);  
    };  
};
```

I'm already struggling!

Ideally I'd like to eventually add more child key's to each object, not just `tag`, but also `id, innerHTML, class` etc.

Any hel would be much appreciated, though please: I'm sure a **framework or library** could do this for me in just a few lines of code, or something similar, but **I'd prefer not to use one** for this particular project.

If you could briefly explain your answers too it'd really help me learn how this all works, and where I went wrong!

Thank you!

NB: I've changed and marked the line in my function that the error message is talking about.

I changed it from:

```
mp.appendChild(obj[i].children);
```

to:

```
mp.appendChild(create(obj[i].children));
```

This is because I want any nested keys in the children object to also be created, so `screen_name` had a children key, they too would be created. **Sorry**, I hope you can understand this!

I'm looking at http://jsperf.com/create-nested-dom-structure for some pointers, this may help you too!

Comment: are you calling this like: `create(nodes);`?

Comment: Since your "create" function already knows how to iterate, why iterate again over the children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "create" function is going to have to be written recursively.

To create a node from your data (in general), you need to:

1. Find the "tag" property and create a new element
2. Give the element the "id" value of the element (taken from the data)
3. For each element in "children", make a node and append it

Thus:

```
function create(elementDescription) {
  var nodes = [];
  for (var n in elementDescription) {
    if (!elementDescription.hasOwnProperty(n)) continue;
    var elem = elementDescription[n];
    var node = document.createElement(elem.tag);
    node.id = n; // optional step
    var cnodes = create(elem.children);
    for (var c = 0; c < cnodes.length; ++c)
      node.appendChild(cnodes[c]);
    nodes.push(node);
  }
  return nodes;
}
```

That will return an array of document elements created from the original "specification" object. Thus from your example, you'd call:

```
var createdNodes = create(nodes);
```

and "createdNodes" would be an array of one element, an `<article>` tag with id "tweets". That element would have two children, an `<h2>` tag with id "screen_name" and a `<p>` tag with id "text".  (Now that I think of it, you might want to skip the "id" assignment unless the node description has an explicit "id" entry, or something.)

Thus if you have a `<div>` in your page called "tweets" (to use your example, though if so you'd definitely want to cut out the "id" setting part of my function), you'd add the results like this:

```
var createdNodes = create(nodes), tweets = document.getElementById('tweets');

for (var eindex = 0; eindex < createdNodes.length; ++eindex)
  tweets.appendChild(createdNodes[eindex]);
```

Comment: He did not indicate that children would have children.

Comment: No, but there are children on the outer node, so one might expect that the general representation would be that a node can contain a "tag" property and a "children" property.  (There might need to be a `<span>` or an `<em>` or something inside the `<p>`, for example.)

Comment: @Josiah: Thank you for your help so far, I apologise for not being more specific. Kudos to you!

Comment: Well @Jonathon It's just going to be a terrible mess if you want to have children with children, as you've already said you might have, if you don't write it recursively.  The recursive version will be **much less code** than some iterated version, which would require you to hard-code another level of loop for each level of nesting your structure might have. If you write it recursively, it'll handle *any* such structure.

Comment: In other words, @Jonathan, you have specified a **naturally recursive problem** with the description of your element descriptor structure, so you should write a recursive solution.

Comment: @Pointy: So I would then just "doc…ById("tweets").appendChild(createdNodes)"? And I still use the same structure for the object I'm passing to the function as a param? This looks awesome.

Comment: Well the code returns an **array** of nodes, so you'd have to iterate through the result array and call "appendChild" on each element.  If you have a `<div>` or something already called "tweets" in the DOM, then you iteratively append to that, yes.

Comment: @Pointy: Like you said, the ID but isn't really required as it'd leave me with elements with duplicate ID's would it not, nor really are key names "tweet", "screen_name" and "text". I'd happily (in fact preferably) pass the function an object like: <code>{{children: {{tag: "h1"}, {children: {{tag: "span"}}, tag: "p"}}, tag: "header"}, {tag: "p"}}</code>

Comment: You could pass it as an array: [{tag: 'div', children: [{tag: 'h1'}, {tag: 'p'}] }]

Comment: @Pointy: could you just clarify what the <code>hasOwnProperty()</code> is about, thanks!

Comment: The `hasOwnProperty()` check verifies that the `for ... in ...` loop isn't stumbling on some property inherited from the "Object" base class of your "node" structure. Some libraries or tools modify the "Object" prototype in such a way as to make it look like *every* object has some common inherited properties. By checking `hasOwnProperty()` we avoid those, which for this purpose would be wrong.

Comment: And if I could guarantee I hadn't modified Object, I could do away with this line?

Comment: Yes, you could, but it's not very expensive. But strictly speaking it's not necessary.

Comment: @Josiah I'm hoping there's a "Epic text per vote ratio" badge :-)

Comment: @Pointy: This works flawlessly! Thank you! Other than voting your answer up and accepting it, is there anything else I could do to reward you! I promise to answer two questions in return to reward the community!

Comment: Nope, just Live Long and Prosper, @Jonathon!

Answer (score 0):

I added a function appendList that accepts a list of elements, and the container to append to. I removed the append to "tweets" part out of the create function to more effectively separate your code.

```
function create(obj) {
    var els = [];
    for(i in obj){  
        var tmp = document.createElement(obj[i].tag);  
        var children;
        if(children = obj[i].children) {  
            var childEls = create(children);
            appendList(childEls, tmp);
        }
        els.push(tmp);
    }; 
    return els;
};
function appendList(list, container){
    for(var i = 0, el; el = list[i]; i++){
        container.appendChild(el);
    }
};
// gets an array of root elements populated with children
var els = create(nodes); 
// appends the array to "tweets"
appendList(els, document.getElementById("tweets"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think that still wouldn't work as I'd be appending a a string (the value of children[prop].tag) and not an element. Furthermore, any child keys nested inside <code>children[prop]</code> would not be appended. I hope this is clear enough, I've updated my question to be more specific too.

Comment: Yah. you clearly need to recursively call the function in this case. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Building on the previous answer: 
I think you still need to create the element you're trying to append:

> tmp.appendChild(children[prop].tag);

should be

> tmp.appendChild(document.createElement(children[prop].tag));

```
function create(obj) {
    for(i in obj){  
        var tmp = document.createElement(obj[i].tag);  
        var children;
        if(children = obj[i].children) {  
            for(var prop in children)
                tmp.appendChild(document.createElement(children[prop].tag));   
        }
        document.getElementById("tweets").appendChild(tmp);  
    };  
};
```

Comment: What if some of the children nodes have children?

Comment: you copied my answer and then explained it in a way that doesn't makes sense. -1

Comment: i added on to your answer by specifying that you still needed to create the element you wanted to append.

Comment: Thank you both for your help so far, we're really getting somewhere with this I think, great collaboration guys!

Comment: @Ken - that should have been a comment

Comment: my apologies. i'm new here. i'll keep that in mind for next time.